# Copy data from CSV to another CSV and populate extra column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

Input:

```
Primary Key    Phone_No
1             9999999999  
2             999-999-9999 
3             024-999-8913
```

Output should be:

```
Primary Key Phone_No  String/Number
1       9999999999       Number
2       999-999-9999     String
3       024-999-8913     String
```

My CSV file has 3 million data.

Will be helpful if someone can help me code in Pandas

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) with [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) if only `numeric` and `string` values:

```
mask = pd.to_numeric(df.Phone_No, errors='coerce').isnull()
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: Phone_No, dtype: bool

df['String/Number'] = np.where(mask, 'String','Number')
print (df)
   Primary Key      Phone_No String/Number
0            1    9999999999        Number
1            2  999-999-9999        String
2            3  024-999-8913        String
```

Comment: One more condition if phone number has "-" , "(" or ")" then it consider to be number.

Comment: One more condition if phone number has "-" , "(" or ")" then it consider to be number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.str.isdigit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.isdigit.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> df['String/Number'] = np.where(df['Phone_No'].str.isdigit(), 'Number', 'String')
>>> df
   PrimaryKey      Phone_No String/Number
0           1    9999999999        Number
1           2  999-999-9999        String
2           3  024-999-8913        String
```

Comment: One more condition if phone number has "-" , "(" or ")" then it consider to be number.

Comment: please adjust your question accordingly then.